# global name "IntVar" not defined

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I defined a class and variables inside that class.
I preceded all the variable names with self.varname.
I don't know what is wrong, but I keep getting "global name 'IntVar' not defined" when trying to run the script

This is part of the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Frame, Button, Label
import time
import random

class fragal(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.mymaster = master
        self.primes = []
        self.cntr1a = 0
        self.cntr1b = 0
        self.cntr2a = 0
        self.cntr2b = 0
        self.count = IntVar()
        self.count.set(0)
        self.time_remaining = IntVar()
        self.time_remaining.set(0)
        self.gamearray = []
        self.equation = StringVar()
        self.equation.set("")
```

Please help!  I have several versions of my program and this version was
working until I started changing the main() loop.

Comment: You haven't imported the `IntVar` class from `tktinter`, hence it's undefined.

Answer (score 9):

`IntVar` is defined in Tkinter. Because you're importing Tkinter "as tk", you need to prefix `IntVar` with `tk.`:

```
self.count = tk.IntVar()
```

You also do not need this line: `from tkinter import Frame, Button, Label` You aren't directly using any of those classes. Plus, you're already importing all of tkinter so you don't need to *also* import just parts of tkinter.

Answer (score 0):

You have not imported `IntVar` from `tkinter` that's why it is undefined. You should impoprt it first by writing this `from tkinter import IntVar`. Now use your `IntVar()` and you will not face this problem again.